# Como indexar meu app nas buscas do Google?

Tags: android, google

Como posso fazer para meu app (Android) começar a aparecer nas buscas do Google?

Edit:

Olha esses prints:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu acho que o próprio PlayStore é quem controla isto, não temos autonomia sobre isto, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: É só você criar uma página web com um link do seu app no Google Play. Se não tiver um site, [preencha o formulário](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/app-only).

Answer (score 4):

Adicione sua URL acessando link:
https://www.google.com.br/intl/pt-BR/add_url.html

Comment: Não é isso que eu preciso, preciso que meu app feito para Android apareça mas buscas do google.

Answer (score -1):

Tem um tipo de indexação que permite vc abrir conteúdos de pesquisa do google diretamente dentro de seu aplicativo. Dá uma olhada nesse [guia](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/) que está em português.

Comment: Evite o uso de links eles podem quebrar, edite a sua resposta e coloque o conteúdo relevante para que possa solucionar a pergunta.

Comment: eu vou atualizar a resposta assim q possível, no momento eu não consigo.